# HResult=0x80131500 Message=Some services are not able to be constructed ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am making a project with simple login and signup functionality and I configured my `Startup.cs` file which is as follows :

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            /* Add Services */
            services.AddServiceExtensions();

            /* Add controllers */
            services.AddControllers();

            /* Cors Extension */
            services.AddCorsExtension();

            /* Swagger Setup */
            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();

            /* Add Mvc Extensions */
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>();

            /* Dynamo Db Setup */
            var dynamoDbConfig = Configuration.GetSection("DynamoDb");
            var runLocalDynamoDb = dynamoDbConfig.GetValue<bool>("LocalMode");

            services.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(sp =>
            {
                var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
                {
                    ServiceURL = dynamoDbConfig.GetValue<string>("LocalServiceUrl")
                };
                return new AmazonDynamoDBClient(clientConfig);
            });

            /* AutoMapper Configuration */
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddMaps(typeof(AutoMapperProfileConfiguration).Assembly);
            });

            services.AddMvcCore();
        }
```

Here I have used the method `AddServiceExtensions` which is as follows :

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceExtensions(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserDataAccess, UserDataAccess>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserDbContext, UserDbContext>();
            //services.AddScoped<ExceptionHandlerFilter>();
            return services;
        }
```

I am working on .Net Core 3.1 and whenever I run the project I get the following error :

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Services.UserServices.IUserService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Services.UserServices.UserService': Unable to resolve service for type 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Entities.DatabaseContext.UserDbContext' while attempting to activate 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.UserDataAccess'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.IUserDataAccess Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.UserDataAccess': Unable to resolve service for type 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Entities.DatabaseContext.UserDbContext' while attempting to activate 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.UserDataAccess'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Gursimran\Hackathon2\NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.API\NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.API\Program.cs:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(System.Type, System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[], bool)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ResultCache, System.Type, System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor, System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain, int)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Type)
    System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey, System.Func<TKey, TValue>)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(System.Type, System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[], bool)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ResultCache, System.Type, System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Services.UserServices.IUserService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Services.UserServices.UserService': Unable to resolve service for type 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Entities.DatabaseContext.UserDbContext' while attempting to activate 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.UserDataAccess'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.Entities.DatabaseContext.UserDbContext' while attempting to activate 'NeighborhoodHelpers.UserMicroservice.DataAccessProvider.UserDataAccess.UserDataAccess'.
```

I am using Dynamodb and hence I have configured that too in the service.
Please help me resolve this issue as I have configured all the services and their interfaces in the `AddServiceExtension` method.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add IUserService and UserService classes code?

Comment: Can you provide the UserService, UserDbContext and UserDataAccess implementations?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you are getting: you have dependencies among your services that require the right order of registration.

Try this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceExtensions(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IUserDataAccess, UserDataAccess>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserDbContext, UserDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    return services;
}
```

if it does not work, please edit your post and provide the constructor code of **IUserService**.